# ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation in SQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have AWS RDS MySql instance. I am using MySql Workbench in order to connect to it. I have created a schema and while trying to import (exported another schema as Self-Contained File) a .sql backup into it, I am getting an error -

> ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one
>   of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I researched about it on internet but couldn't found a working solution yet.

Comment: What kind of import is that?

Comment: @James I simply exported another schema as Self-Contained File. I am trying to import it.

Comment: @James yes .sql file. Steps -> Administrator tab -> Data Import/Restore

Comment: The error says you don't have privilege. What user did you used to import?

Comment: @James default master user that AWS RDS provides

Comment: Have you tried running the sql directly from the query window like opening the .sql and clicking the thunder symbol(1st symbol next to save button)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201012/discussion-between-raghav-and-james).